# Burp to Powershell with Cookie

Tags: powershell, burp

The following is a truncated capture from Burp:

[image]

Forwarding this capture using Burp's repeater generates the expected response.
What is the right way to rebuild this into Powershell's Invoke-WebRequest?

I have tried the following but no dice. Not getting the same response as with forwarding the original request using Burp.

```
$URL = "https://portals.aliexpress.com/adcenter/generateUrl.htm"
$WebSession = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
$MyCookie = New-Object System.Net.Cookie 
$MyCookie.Name = "ALIEXPRESS_SESSION"

$MyCookie.Domain = ".aliexpress.com"

$CookieParams = @{
        ali_apache_id='10.182.xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        cna='Y3OFExxxxxxxxxxxx';
        _ga='GA1.2.1xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        ....
        ....
    }

$MyCookie.Value = $CookieParams
$WebSession.Cookies.Add($MyCookie)

$TokenParams = @{
        _csrf_token_='xxxxxxxxx';
        action='GenerateUrlAction';
        targetUrl='https%3A%2F%2Fwww.aliexpress.com%2Fitem%2FOriginal-SPALDING-NBA-Graffiti-Series-Rubber-Outdoor-Basketball-83-574Y%2F32972474387.html%3Fspm%3D2114.33020108.6.3.23a1y1fQy1fQWV%26scm%3D1007.17258.122813.0%26pvid%3D3d3c706f-950c-45e8-8b10-6efc729703a4';
        trackId='thexxxxxxxxxx';
        eventSubmitDoGenerateUrl='Get+Tracking+Link';

    }

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL -WebSession $WebSession -Method Post -Body $TokenParams
```

Comment: I believe the cookies are not being created correctly. You'll want to use a `System.Net.CookieCollection` object in `$WebSession.Cookies.Add` if you want to add multiple cookies at once. Otherwise you'll need to iterate over the `$CookieParams` hashtable and create a cookie from each and then add it into the `CookieContainer`. I'm hesitant to post an answer as I don't have any method to test my idea that I know of.

Comment: That's interesting. I'll try that. What should I put for each cookie name and domain though? or does it not matter even?

Comment: The cookies should match what burp shows, the overload definition I think you'll want to use is `System.Net.Cookie new(string name, string value)`. I'm not sure if you need to specify the domain when adding a cookie but if you do use the overload `void Add(uri uri, System.Net.Cookie cookie)` otherwise use `void Add(System.Net.Cookie cookie)` for `$WebSession.Cookies.Add()`.